# *ngIf based on another *ngIf

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created the following code with two `*ngFor`s and two `*ngIf`s.

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contactList">
  <span>{{contact.name.formatted}}</span>
  <div *ngFor="let number of contact.phoneNumbers">
    <span *ngIf="number.type == 'mobile'">{{number.value}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I hide the first span if the second is hidden? I know I can do this by using JavaScript loops but I'd like to do this in the template if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to use the same ngIf on the first span since you want to hide the 2nd and 1st span. So you should use the first span within the ngFor

```
  <div *ngFor="let number of contact.phoneNumbers">
   <ng-container ngIf="number.type == 'mobile'">
    <span>{{contact.name.formatted}}</span>
    <span>{{number.value}}</span>
   </ng-container>
  </div>
```